# What is the difference between Narayana Maya and Asuras?

Tags: vishnu, asuras, brihadaranyaka-upanishad

According to Brihadaranyaka Upanishad, chapter 1, Third Brahmana,  it is said that Asuras win against gods when one follows his natural inclinations such as wanting to eat something that tastes good etc.

Narayana Maya also comes in the form of a desire. Then what is the difference between Narayana Maya and working of Asura in oneself?

Comment: Give a specific reference to the Brihadaranyaka.

Comment: Chapter 1 - Third Bramhana (The Superiority of Vital Force among all Functions)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what exactly do you refer to as Narayana Maya?